Probability predictions in random forest and bagging with aggregating not a vote count: seeking documentation/existing research
Typically, across an entire bagging or random forest ensemble, class probabilities are determined through a vote count method. Within that ensemble, each tree makes a class prediction based on the majority class in a terminal node. Let $T$ be the total number of trees and $b_t$ be the $t$-th tree in the ensemble. Let $\mathbb{I}(b_t(x_i) = A)$ be the indicator function that returns $1$ when $b_t$ predicts that observation $x_i$ belongs to class $A$. The probability of class $A$ for observation $x_i$ is calculated as:
$$
\Pr(x_i = A) = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{I}(b_t(x_i) = A). 
$$
A different method is that probability predictions are computed for each $b_t$ then averaged across the ensemble. It appears this this method is used in RandomForestClassifier.predict in Python. Although I am an R user with randomForest. In maths, this is:
$$
\Pr(x_i = A) = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} \Pr(b_t(x_i) = A). 
$$
I am seeking evidence of the relative performance of each method. Ideally, a simulation study to assist with my understanding in this area. I have looked around but I cant quite find anything out there. My intuition from the limited reading is that probability predictions from each CART model are so poor that their aggregate is a poor estimate of the probability anyway.

Some keywords to look for are "hard voting" and "soft voting". I think soft voting (the second method you describe) is considered better but I've not looked into the literature about it.

CART is a known "weak learner" but bootstrap aggregation makes the ensemble a strong learner.  It looks like your equations are trying to find the mean per-class accuracy.  Is that right?

@EngrStudent I don't think that first sentence is correct: a full-grown CART tree is a strong learner, overfitting, and bagging weakens it to generalize better. Stumps or other short trees are weak, usually using some flavor of boosting to aggregate them into strong(er) learners.

@EngrStudent but I'm not sure if any of that is relevant to this reference request?...

In terms of terminology, the first method you describe is often referred to as "majority voting" or "consensus." However, note that even if $br(x_i)$ is unbiased still
$$
\Pr(x_i = A) \neq \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{I}(b_t(x_i) = A) \right)
$$
The proportion of votes does not necessarily equal the probability that $x_i = A$. For example, suppose $Pr(x_i = A) = 0.9$, and each tree classifies $x_i$ as $A$. Then the RHS = 1 which does not equal 0.9.
Instead of majority voting, one can average the estimated probability from each tree. Here if $b_t(x_i)$ is unbiased then
$$
\Pr(x_i = A) = \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} Pr(b_t(x_i)  = A) \right). 
$$
Per Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman (2008), in the case of bagging, averaging the probabilities improves estimates of class probability and reduces variances especially for the case of a small number of bootstrap replicates. See Elements of Statistical Learning section 8.7.1 for a simple simulation where averaging outperforms majority voting for bagging with less than ~100 bootstraps after which prediction errors for both methods are similar. For more extensive simulations, see section 7.3 of Bauer and Kohavi (1999) who find that, in the case of bagging, averaging probabilities outperforms voting.
The intuition here is that bagging generally works because it reduces variance (through aggregating classifiers) and doesn't effect bias. In the case of majority voting (as opposed to averaging), though, bagging can increase bias if you have a bad classifier e.g. suppose $Pr(x_i = A) = 1$ but $\mathbb{E}(b_t(x)) = 0.45$. The expected bias with averaging is $0.55$ but with voting its $1$.
For a more detailed explanation see the relevant section in Elements of Statistical Learning.
This is a big topic, and I'd be interested in what other sources say or what the general consensus is on this.

Regarding your first paragraph, I think the asker meant the LHS to be the predicted probability, rather than some inherent truth.

@BenReiniger yes but I think this is still an important distinction in expectation. Edited to clarify that.

Part 1: comparing the expression.
You want to compare this:
$$ Pr\left(x_i=A\right) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=i}^{T}\mathbb{I}\left(b_t\left(x_i\right)=A\right) $$
with this:
$$ Pr\left(x_i=A\right) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=i}^{T}Pr\left(b_t\left(x_i\right)=A\right)$$
They are both expectations over an ensemble.
Removing the expectation, the respective expressions for the $i^{th}$ term are this:
$$ \mathbb{I}\left(b_t\left(x_i\right)=A\right) $$
and this:
$$Pr\left(b_t\left(x_i\right)=A\right) $$
An indicator function is defined as:
$$ \mathbb{I}_{A}\left(x\right) := \left\{\begin{matrix}
 1 \:  \text{if} \: x \in A \\
0 \: \text{if} \: x \notin A 
\end{matrix}\right.  $$
when looking at nominal classification accuracy $A = \{1 \} $.
The indicator can be thought of as the result of applying the heaviside step function to the probability with a threshold.
$$ \mathcal H \left( x \right) :=  \left\{\begin{matrix}
 1 \:  \text{if} \: x \ge 0 \\
 0 \: \text{if} \: x \lt 0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
If the heaviside step occurs at the mean, in the limit of "large" $T$ they can be equal.
There are likely practical issues such as speed, problem size, sample count, and such that can differentiate them.
Part 2: weak and strong learner.
First, lets define "weak":
A weak learner produces a classifier which is only slightly more accurate than random classification.
— Page 21, Pattern Classification Using Ensemble Methods, 2010.
Friedman, J. H. (2001). Greedy function approximation: a gradient boosting machine. Annals of statistics, 1189-1232.
The function $h\left(x;a_m\right)$ is called a "weak learner" or "base learner" and is usually a classification tree.
Some other references:

Andrew Moore tutorials - check out decision tree tutorial slides 58 to 80 where it talks about how easy it is to overfit, and how "magic" parameters are needed for pruning to reduce overfit.  This is the definition of overfit.
Supervised Machine Learning by Michael Foley, section on Gradient Boosting where it explicitly defines the CART/Tree element of GBM as a "weak learner".
Numerous papers like this, where the CART is defined as a weak learner.


I still don't see how part 2 is relevant to the question. We're interested in random forests, which generally operate on (nearly-)fully expanded trees, not the shallow trees often used as weak learners in boosting.

I think part 1 stops short of a complete answer: if it's true that "in the limit of 'large' T they can be equal" (which I'm not entirely convinced by, but also I don't know what you meant by the heaviside applying at the mean), then it's still left to understand if one method is better for smallish $T$, whether theoretically or for some benchmark datasets.

@BenReiniger - the third comment to the main question, yours, is about whether a CART is considered "weak".  Everything has its best spots and worse spots.  I think it is not the best word, but its the nomenclature.  I knew some folks who make a random forest of GBM's, and a GBM is considered strong, so you can ensemble strong things too.  i think the nomenclature is from the 90's or even the 80's and is a poor descriptor.

But the Question here doesn't mention strong/weak, and I don't think that's particularly relevant to the Question.  I am interested in following up on that, maybe in chat to start?

@BenReiniger - make it a question, get points.  :D
